Problem on 5l0380R
I have a sat recever with this power supply. All rectifier diodes burn and replace them and also 5l0380 R was burned and I change it with a new one but it burn. I checked all components around it and semes theme's correct. What causes the switch IC to burn? The pictures in attachment.


Thanks in advance
